# How to generate empirical c.d.f from a set of observations?

Tags: r, cdf, cumulative-frequency

Assume that I have a vector `x = c(1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 4)`. I would like to ask if there is a function to generate the [cdf](/questions/tagged/cdf) of this data. My desire result is

```
               x    c.d.f
1              0      1/7
2              1      3/7
3              3      4/7
4              4      6/7
5              5      7/7
```

I tried function `ecdf(c(1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 4))`, but I don't understand the resulted value of this function

```
Empirical CDF 
Call: ecdf(c(1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 4))
 x[1:5] =      0,      1,      3,      4,      5
```

Could you please help me generate this c.d.f? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ecdf` returns a function. You get your desired output using

```
Fn <- ecdf(x)
out <- data.frame(x = knots(Fn), cdf = Fn(knots(Fn)))
out
#  x       cdf
#1 0 0.1428571
#2 1 0.4285714
#3 3 0.5714286
#4 4 0.8571429
#5 5 1.0000000
```

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/how-to-calculate-cumulative-distribution-in-r

Answer (score 2):

The `ecdf` function returns a function. To get your desired result, call the resulting function on the original vector.

```r
x <- c(1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 4)

Fn <- ecdf(x)
class(Fn)
#> [1] "ecdf"     "stepfun"  "function"
Fn(x)
#> [1] 0.4285714 0.4285714 0.5714286 0.1428571 0.8571429 1.0000000 0.8571429
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>